# Got "there is no books attribute in the dict" in Python when use dot to get the dict value like I do in Jinja template

Tags: python, flask, httprequest

I'm having a problem with accessing the response data from my http request. I'm able to get it if I pass the response through to my html and then take the specific data I want out of it but if I try to take that same part of the response in my python file and pass that through to my html it says "there is no books attribute in the dict".

my html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block heading %}
Search Page
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}

the result of the http request:
<p>  {{res}} </p>


I want to add this info from the request
<p>{{res.books[0].average_rating}}
{{res.books[0].work_ratings_count}}</p>


to this dictionary

{{apiDict}}

but the when I use the same syntax to access the average rating and ratings count 
from 
'res' in my python file it says the respose has no book object, why does this 
happen?

{% endblock %}
```

Here is my python/flask code:

```
@app.route("/api/<isbn>", methods=["GET"])
def apiacc(isbn):
res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params=. 
{"key": "lzhHXUd9kUpum244vufV2Q", "isbns": isbn}).json()
# avg = res.books[0].average_rating
# rc = res.books[0].work_ratings_count
book = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn = :i", {"i": isbn}).fetchone()
db.commit()


apiDict = {
    "title": book.title,
    "author": book.author,
    "year": book.year,
    "isbn": isbn
}
# apiDict["average_score"] = res.books[0].average_rating
# apiDict["review_count"] = res.books[0].work_ratings_count

return render_template("api.html", res = res, apiDict=apiDict)
```

I would like to have the python code like this:

```
 apiDict = {
    "title": book.title,
    "author": book.author,
    "year": book.year,
    "isbn": isbn,
    "average_score": avg,
    "review_count": rc
 }
```

and just pass in the apiDict to api.hmtl as the only value but I get the error I mentioned earlier.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoVs3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `res` returned by requests will be a dict. In the template, Jinja support to get the dict value with the dot operator, like:

```
{{ res.books }}
```

But in Python, you have to use the bracket operator to get the value in a dict (dot operator used to get the attribute):

```
data = res['books']
```